# Is there some commit reminder for Subversion/etc for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

Something that will alert your/force you to commit after editing X number of files, or modifying X number of lines of code, or writing X number of lines of code.

Edit:
There's clearly no feasible way for an automated system to determine if some realizable code chunk is complete but this would be good enough for me. I don't want to use this as an "autosave" feature but more as a brain jog to remember to commit once at a suitable point.

Comment: When you finish something you feel is worth on its own, just commit it. There is no problem of having too many commits, it is bad if you have too few :)

Comment: My problem is, I forget completely about committing small chunks and end up having implemented a days worth of chunks. Then I get to dig through changes to commit related bits in smaller commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completely agree with the other anwsers, but I think one can use this approach if, say, you want to ensure that you make small commits rather than large ones, especially in DVCS's like Git

I think you can setup a Scheduled Task or Cron, which will hit your working directory and run something like:

```
svn diff | grep -E "^\+ " | wc -l
```

and if the count is greater than something that you deem is when you want to commit, you can make it give you a reminder. I don't think you can integrate such a thing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

That's not what commits are for. They are not some sort of backup mechanism. You do a commit when a piece of work has reached some state that you want to remember, normally because you are happy with it. It makes no sense at all to do them every X hours or every N lines of code.

Comment: Yep and I didn't mean to imply that I wanted it as a "backup". A reminder would jog my brain into thinking "Oh yeah, I should commit after I finish this or - crap, should have committed that chunk a couple seconds ago" instead of "crap, now I get to sift through and merge pieces because I completely spaced it"

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's just a workflow thing and a habit you should get into.

Commits should be related to the work you are doing - so that reverting is meaningful. It's pretty hard for anything else to detect that except you.